# Multiple inserts with use of Identity in next INSERT with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I have following code snippet trying to perform multiple inserts using Entity Framework 6.0.2.  I am using the `Database.BeginTransaction()` discuss in the [MSDN Working with Transactions (EF6 Onwards)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843) article.

```
using(var context = new Sys.EntityModels.ERPPermissionMgmtEntities())
{
    using (var dbContextTran = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            if (application.Id == 0)
            {
                Sys.EntityModels.Applications a = ConvertObjToEntity(application);

                //add the application information to the Applications database table
                context.Applications.Add(a);

                applicationId = a.ApplicationId;
            }

            //loop through the Roles property list to add the Application/Role relationship to the Application_Role_Mappings table
            if (application.Roles != null)
            {
                foreach (Entity.Role role in application.Roles)
                {
                    if (role.Id == 0)
                    {
                        Sys.EntityModels.Roles r = ConvertObjToEntity(role);

                        //add the role information to the Roles table
                        context.Roles.Add(r);

                        roleId = r.RoleId;
                     }


                     //insert a Application/Role mapping into the Application_Role_Mappings table
                     Sys.EntityModels.Application_Role_Mappings arm = new Sys.EntityModels.Application_Role_Mappings
                     {
                         ApplicationId = applicationId,
                         RoleId = roleId,
                         CreatedBy = application.CreatedBy.EmployeeID,
                         DateTimeCreated = System.DateTime.Now
                     };

                     context.Application_Role_Mappings.Add(arm);
                 }
             }

             SaveChanges(context);

             dbContextTran.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            dbContextTran.Rollback();
            updateSuccessful = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I insert the `Sys.EntityModels.Application` object into the `Applications` table, I need the identity from the that insert to use when I insert a record into the `Application_Role_Mapping` table.  How do I secure the record identity from my first insert without doing a separate insert outside of the `BeginTransaction` using statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a call to `SaveChanges()` after you add the application. Entity Framework will fix the ID for you:

```
//add the application information to the Applications database table
context.Applications.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();
applicationId = a.ApplicationId;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to implement the `SaveChanges(false)` and `AcceptAllChanges` but those are only available in `ObjectContext` not the `DbContext` object type